# Lucene: searching/filtering by field's value length

Tags: java, search, lucene

I need some help doing a search.
Say I have a really simple document structure, just 1 field, labeled name.
I need to retrieve all the names whose length is more or less than a specified value. By length I mean String.length().
A range filter seems close in concept, but I couldn't find a good example to write my specific case.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: The easiest solution appears to be to create a second field that contains the length. I'm not sure how the index for the `name` field could be used to efficiently query by its length.

Comment: I guess I could create that field, index by it and then do a range filter/query. Seems to me that there should be a more direct solution, but this is a good suggestion.

Comment: There could be a more direct solution, I'm only a newbie with Lucene (that's why I wrote my suggestion as a comment rather than an answer) but this is certainly what I'd do.

Comment: I got the same answer from lucene users list. I'm going to wait a bit more and go that way. If you care about the points you can add it as an answer and I'll mark this as resolved.

Comment: Creating a NumericField using the length is a reasonable suggestion, you can then use a  RangeQuery to extract your results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a NumericField using the length, then use a RangeQuery. See NumericField javadoc's for an example.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic example of a MultiTermQuery.  It's not in the box, but easy to implement.  Take a look at `WildCardQuery` which extends `MultiTermQuery`.  This does something very similar.  Just use a different FilterredTermEnum like this one which uses the length of the term.text to filter the terms (not the term text itself).

The magic happens here (this code is in the custom term enumerator at the bottom of my post):

```
protected internal override bool TermCompare(Term term)
{
  if (field == term.Field())
  {
    System.String searchText = term.Text();
    if (searchText.Length >= text.Length())
    {
      return true;
    }
  }
  endEnum = true;
  return false;
}
```

The above code looks through all the terms for the field and checks their lengths against the length of the term passed in the constructor.  It yields true for any field that is at least that long.

```
public class MinLengthQuery : MultiTermQuery
{
  public MinLengthQuery(Term term) : base(term)
  {
  }

  protected internal override FilteredTermEnum GetEnum(IndexReader reader)
  {
    return new MinLengthTermEnum(reader, GetTerm());
  }
}
```

This class does all the work:

```
public class MinLengthTermEnum : FilteredTermEnum
{
internal Term searchTerm;
internal System.String field = "";
internal System.String text = "";
internal System.String pre = "";
internal int preLen = 0;
internal bool endEnum = false;

public MinLengthTermEnum(IndexReader reader, Term term):base()
{
  searchTerm = term;
  field = searchTerm.Field();
  text = searchTerm.Text();
  SetEnum(reader.Terms(new Term(searchTerm.Field(), "")));
}

protected internal override bool TermCompare(Term term)
{
  if (field == term.Field())
  {
    System.String searchText = term.Text();
    if (searchText.Length >= text.Length())
    {
      return true;
    }
  }
  endEnum = true;
  return false;
}

public override float Difference()
{
  return 1.0f;
}

public override bool EndEnum()
{
  return endEnum;
}
public override void  Close()
{
  base.Close();
  searchTerm = null;
  field = null;
  text = null;
}
}
```

(I'm a lucene.net guy, but the translation ought be be easy enough... It would probably be easier to start with your version of Lucene's source code for WildCardQuery and TermEnum and work from it).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer! Converting it to java was indeed easy enough.
However I think there's a problem: this assumes that the terms are ordered by the enumerated criteria and I don't think that's the case.
If the index has the following content:
aaaa
aaaabbbb
bbbb

...and the query asks for lengths less than 5 it seems like this will stop enumerating at the 2nd element and miss the 3rd.
I tweaked your endEnum() method to use return actualEnum.term()==null; and that works, however seems like that transformed an index search into a linear search for that term.

Comment: I tested it with a simple query and a small database (~17k docs) and adding this criterion changed the query time from <10ms to 284ms.
I could add a length field and index by it, but that is now very close to the initial suggestion.
What do you think?

Comment: Looks like I don't understand that stuff as well as I thought.  I'm shooting from the hip here, but shouldn't it make sure it's looking over the correct field... otherwise, won't it continue on to the next field?(`actualEnum.term().field() == expectedField || actualEnum.term()==null`).  I thought the TermEnumerator would start at one field, go through all the terms for that field, then advance to the next field... until it reaches the last term of the last field.

Comment: I've now realized that I was referring to documents and the enumerator is about terms. This is turning too time consuming for me. I'm going to try the first suggestion and if that doesn't work I'll get back trying this. Still thanks a lot for your help!